# SQL : Update value when the value in the database is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is already asked question and possible to be close.
But i really want a answer, I already searched through the internet, Read documentations, Blogs, and Question to SO.

This is my Query so Far,

```
declare @count numeric
select @count = (select count(1) from E496_TitleReference a where
exists (select 1 from #tempTransactions b where  a.EPEB_RoD = b.tEPEB_RoD  and 
a.EPEB_ENO = b.tEPEB_ENO and a.EPEB_ID = b.tEPEB_ID and a.Title_Seq = b.tTitle_Seq))

update E496_TitleReference
set PrintStatus = '{0}',Is_AESM=isnull(-1,Is_AESM)
from E496_TitleReference a where
exists (select 1 from #tempTransactions b where  a.EPEB_RoD = b.tEPEB_RoD  and 
a.EPEB_ENO = b.tEPEB_ENO and a.EPEB_ID = b.tEPEB_ID and a.Title_Seq = b.tTitle_Seq)

if @@rowcount <> @count
begin
     rollback tran
     Print "Error: There is an error on table E496_TitleReference."
     return
end
go
```

For eg, In my table in `Database` i have column name `Is_AESM`, In `Is_AESM` column it have 4 values.

```
Is_AESM
NULL
NULL
-1
-2
```

Something like this.
Now when i run my script, it has no problem when i run it,

```
 Is_AESM=isnull(-1,Is_AESM)
```

In this query it will detect if `Is_AESM` is `null`, it will update `Is_AESM` = `-1` if not it will retain the value.

Now my problem is, if my query detect `Is_AESM` has a `null` value, it will update all the value to `-1`.

```
Is_AESM
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

The result is something like that. Now i want is update only the null value not all the value in column `Is_AESM`.

I think this query is wrong `Is_AESM=isnull(-1,Is_AESM)`.

Any ideas will be a big help.

Comment: Is_AESM=IF(Is_AESM = " ",-1,Is_AESM) ?

Answer (score 2):

You may try with coalsece() function

```
update E496_TitleReference
set PrintStatus = '{0}',Is_AESM=coalsece(Is_AESM,-1)
from E496_TitleReference a where
exists (select 1 from #tempTransactions b where  a.EPEB_RoD = b.tEPEB_RoD  and 
a.EPEB_ENO = b.tEPEB_ENO and a.EPEB_ID = b.tEPEB_ID and a.Title_Seq = b.tTitle_Seq)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace order of parameters.

```
Is_AESM=isnull(Is_AESM, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALSECE function. It returns the first non-null entry from the given list. So:

```
Is_AESM= COALSECE(IS_AESM,-1)
```

This will return *IS_AESM* value if it is not null (since it is the first non-null value)

Else if *IS_AESM* is NULL then it returns *-1* (since it is the non-null value)